# PHP outputs wrongly encoded HTML src through basename()

Tags: php, html, encoding

The following PHP code finds files in the directory `images/galerias/minerales/brutos/`and outputs HTML depending on the folders/images inside of it.

```
<?php
    $folders = glob('images/galerias/minerales/brutos/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach($folders as $folder) {
        echo "<section id='".str_replace(' ', '', (basename($folder)))."' class='gallery'><div id='categoryimg'><p>".basename($folder)."</p></div><!-- SECTION -->".PHP_EOL;
            $files = glob("images/galerias/minerales/brutos/".basename($folder)."/*.{jpg}", GLOB_BRACE);
            foreach($files as $file) {
                echo "<div>".PHP_EOL."    <p>".basename($file, ".jpg")."</p>".PHP_EOL."    <img src='$file' alt='".basename($file, ".jpg")."'>".PHP_EOL."</div>".PHP_EOL;
            }
        echo "</section>";
    }
?>
```

This works flawlessly on my local server but on the live server it outputs (among other irrelevant lines) stuff like this:

```
<img src='images/galerias/regalosmagicos/Otros/Atrapasue#U00f1os.jpg' alt='Atrapasue#U00f1os'>
```

Notice the wrongly encoded "Atrapasueños" which appears as "Atrapasue#U00f1os". This causes the website to fail rendering images with special characters in the filename. Considering this works well on my server, **I would like to find a suggestion as to where I should change configurations in my server in order to have my PHP output correctly encoded lines.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it myself - the problem was not the server nor the PHP script, but I discovered whenever I uploaded a file with a name such as `Sandía.jpg` **the cPanel file manager would automatically change it** to `Sand%EDa.jpg` or something similar. So there's something else I have to troubleshoot but at least I know my code was working from the start.

- cPanel version: cPanel, Inc.  11.52.2.2
- cPanel language set to: Spanish

### Update

There was not only a problem with the cPanel file manager but also with Kubuntu's **Ark** archive manager. Both introduced encoding issues. What a mess, just take into account that encoding problems could come from anywhere.

*I'm leaving this answer here because it might help somebody else who thinks they're having server-side encoding problems and they might want to check the cPanel file manager too.*